# Jquery UI Draggable/Sortable without holding the mouse button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I was searching for the solution across the site, however did not find anything. I am facing a problem where I need to redo the style of dragging. I am using jquery ui for the draggable/sortable part. However, I need to create a new behaviour: That is, I click the handler, release the left buttom, with mousemove, the element would stick to the cursor, with another click, the element would drop. Overally, I need to disable the mousedown part during dragging.

**EDIT:**

Right, so here is a simple sortable example. What I need is, that when I click the handle .article-header, it will stick to the mouse without holding holding mousedown. So in other words, I would need a behaviour where I can have the handle class active when clicking on it, however still active on first mouseup, then dragging it with mousemove without actually holding the mousedown and on other click, it will drop.

```
$(".articles:not(.nosort)").sortable({
    handle : '.article-header',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update : function (ev,that) {
    var
        order = $(ev.target).sortable('serialize');
        //Saving the order to db
    }
});


<ul class="articles" data-handler="articles">

        <li id="article-list_1">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum 1</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li id="article-list_2">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum 2</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li id="article-list_3">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum 3</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li id="article-list_4">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum 4</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li id="article-list_5">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum 5</h4>
            </div>
        </li>

</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2x2n/

Comment: Please provide code or a jsfiddle example

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Draggable() and keyboard control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282573/jquery-draggable-and-keyboard-control)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around how the `$.ui.mouse` widget works and I found out that the solution is essentially quite easy.

I've extended the prototype of mouseMove and mouseUp. Firstly, I don't need to check, whether the mouse has made any distance while mouseDown.

Secondly, I've commented the part, where they are unbinding mousemove after mouseup event has been called. Hence, you just need to unbind the mousemove event for instance in the update event of sortable widget.

I am not sure, whether this is the right approach, however, if somebody has better suggestions, I will be happy to approve their answers.

```
$.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMove = function(event) {
        // IE mouseup check - mouseup happened when mouse was out of window
        if ($.ui.ie && !(document.documentMode >= 9) && !event.button) {
            return this._mouseUp(event);
        }

        if (this._mouseStarted) {
            this._mouseDrag(event);
            return event.preventDefault();
        }

        // if (this._mouseDistanceMet(event) && this._mouseDelayMet(event)) {
            this._mouseStarted =
                (this._mouseStart(this._mouseDownEvent, event) !== false);
            (this._mouseStarted ? this._mouseDrag(event) : this._mouseUp(event));
        // }
        return !this._mouseStarted;
    }
 $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseUp = function(event) {
        $(document)
            // .unbind('mousemove.'+this.widgetName, this._mouseMoveDelegate)
            .unbind('mouseup.'+this.widgetName, this._mouseUpDelegate);

        if (this._mouseStarted) {
            this._mouseStarted = false;

            if (event.target === this._mouseDownEvent.target) {
                $.data(event.target, this.widgetName + '.preventClickEvent', true);
            }

            this._mouseStop(event);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Sortable update function

```
update : function (ev,that) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.'+$.ui.sortable.prototype.widgetName, $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMoveDelegate);
}
```